# Firebase set method erasing collection before population (using node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Tl;dr:**

Implemented in `node.js` (`firebase-admin`), when using the `set` method on (Realtime Database) it seems to be first clearing the collection and then populating the data itself.

**Actual question:**

We have some code that is triggered by listening to a specific collection in firebase. When the calculation is done, a target collection needs to be updated (using the `set` method). We have observed some weird behaviour where it seems that the target collection is being cleared and then the data is populated.

The expected behaviour of Firebase `set` method is to "work out" the diff and perform a smaller, more exact update (remove certain keys or change their value for instance).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr:**

Our code was performing multiple updates (`sets` actions) to the same target collection, where one of them was clearing all the data and the other populating it.

**Actual answer:**

Worked out that due to some changes done, the code that was listening to the triggering collection ran twice. The two versions ran at the same time but resulted in different outcomes (due to some parameters). We then got a race condition for these two lines:

`..ref(`${targetCollection}`).set(null)`

`..ref(`${targetCollection}`).set(newData)`